# SELECT column FROM tab1 WHERE test=test AND (SELECT col FROM tab2 WHERE qwe=qwe)? Is it possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

How to make query like this:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE ppp=$parameter 
AND (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE parameter=$parameter AND qweqwe=$parameter2)
```

PS: '$' not from PHP, I just show that this values are variable.

Actually, I need `AND qweqwe<650` in the second query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
   column1 
FROM 
   table1 
WHERE 
   ppp=$parameter 
   AND EXISTS
       (
           SELECT
               NULL
           FROM
               table2
           WHERE
               table1.ppp=table2.parameter
               AND qweqwe<$parameter2
    )
```

Comment: Yes. It works try it yourself. You can have whatever `SELECT 'tut'`, `SELECT 1`,`SELECT NULL`,`SELECT 'SOMEOTHER'`. It is just a style of writing a `EXISTS`. If you are using linq-to-sql it actually translate the `contains` function to an `EXISTS` with `SELECT NULL`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE parameter=$parameter 
AND  exists 
(SELECT 1 FROM table2 WHERE table2.parameter=table1.parameter AND table2.qweqwe=$parameter2)
```

Comment: This will not work. If you do not fix the typo `exist` = `EXISTS`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on you data.
You can either use exists as shown in previous answers or use join.

```
 SELECT column1  FROM table1 
 join table2 on table1.ppp=table2.parameter  and  table2.qweqwe=$parameter2
 where table1.ppp=$parameter
```

In most cases join will be much faster then exists. But it can turn out that you have to use distinct if there's more then one recotd in table2 for each record in table1

Answer (score 0):

what exactly are you trying to do?
the thing after first AND should be logical, for example

```
... AND 650<(SELECT qweqwe FROM table2 WHERE parameter=$parameter2)
```